# Uber menu, manual integration, disable Mobile

Tags: menus, mobile

i use uber menu plugin for my theme.
my theme (pointfinder) require manual integration code.It works perfectly, but I would turn it off completely on the mobile
I used the following form (if else)to disable it and got an error. sorry I'm not a dev.

```
<?php
function pointfinder_menucolumn_get(){
?>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9" id="pfmenucol1">
        <div class="pf-menu-container">


    if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
            <nav id="pf-primary-nav" class="pf-nav-dropdown clearfix">
                <ul class="pf-nav-dropdown pfnavmenu pf-topnavmenu">
                    <?php pointfinder_navigation_menu ();?>
                    <?php 
                        if (PFPBSIssetControl('general_postitembutton_status','','1') == 1) {
                    ?>
                    <li id="pfpostitemlink" class="main-menu-item  menu-item-even menu-item-depth-0 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children">
                      <a class="menu-link main-menu-link">
                          <div class="postanitem-inner">
                              <span class="pfadmicon-glyph-478"></span><?php echo PFPBSIssetControl('general_postitembutton_buttontext','','Post an Item');?>
                          </div>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php 
                        }; 
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </nav>  
    <?php                                               
    }
    else {

        if ( function_exists( 'ubermenu' ) ): 
            if ( PFPBSIssetControl('general_postitembutton_status','','1') == 1) { ?>
                <div id="pfpostitemlink" >
                    <a class="menu-link main-menu-link">
                        <div class="postanitem-inner">
                            <span class="pfadmicon-glyph-478"></span><?php echo PFPBSIssetControl('general_postitembutton_buttontext','','Post an Item');?>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            <?php 
            };

            ubermenu( 'main' , array( 'theme_location' => 'pointfinder-main-menu' ) ); 

            else: 

            ?>
                <nav id="pf-primary-nav" class="pf-nav-dropdown clearfix">
                    <ul class="pf-nav-dropdown pfnavmenu pf-topnavmenu">
                        <?php 
                            pointfinder_navigation_menu ();
                            if (PFPBSIssetControl('general_postitembutton_status','','1') == 1) {
                        ?>
                        <li id="pfpostitemlink" class="main-menu-item  menu-item-even menu-item-depth-0 menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children">
                            <a class="menu-link main-menu-link">
                                <div class="postanitem-inner">
                                    <span class="pfadmicon-glyph-478"></span><?php echo PFPBSIssetControl('general_postitembutton_buttontext','','Post an Item');?>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <?php 
                            };
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </nav>   
<?php       
    endif; 
    }
?>
```

for manual integration use this:

http://sevenspark.com/docs/ubermenu-3/theme-integration/pointfinder

thk a lot

Comment: Please add your code directly into your post. I see you have done a lot of edits, and it seems code formatting in your post is an issue, you can check [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code) which will help you to learn how to properly format code in posts ;-)